# How to relocate all variabile defined in a precompiled (.a) library from bss to a specific section?

Tags: gcc

We are using a precompiled library that defines a huge amount of static variables; they doen't fit in the standard bss section (internal ram of an MCU).
We need to move them in another section mapped on external ram.
We cant' move all bss to external ram.

All attempts to edit the linker script fails

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: We have an MCU with 64k internal ram mapped at 0x1000000 and 32M in external SDRAM mapped at 0xA0000000.     bss section is mapped in the first 64k so.   We link a precompiled (.a) library in the project and this library declares a lot of global variables that doesn't fit in the first 64k.